# Is there a way to have shortcut for text in Java?

Tags: java, object

I am trying to avoid repeating masses of code and was wondering if there was a short cut for it? I want a literal shortcut, which just replaces the shortcut with text in compilation.

for example:

```
private int a = 0;
/*Shortcut sc = new Shortcut ( for(a = 0; a < 5; a++) ); */

if (truth = true)
sc.doTask(a);
else
sc.doTask((a+1);
```

I know it doesn't affect the efficiency of coding, but makes the task look a bit more organized.

Comment: a shortcut would be to learn java.  Yes use methods.  Also `if (truth = true)` does not equals `if (truth == true)` - it's the truth.

Comment: or better, `if (truth)`

Comment: Many IDEs to this, NetBeans actually allows you to define your own...

Answer (score 0):

It seems what you are trying to do is will leave your code unmaintainable and hard to read (Unless you were asking how to organize your code in functions).
It's not always about coding efficiency. You have to make sure that your code is not harder to maintain and understand by other developers.

If you want to avoid repetition of code put the repeated code in some well defined methods.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test();
        // Now you can use the so called shortcut that is called a method everywhere you want.
        int sum = test.getSum(1, 2, 3);

        System.out.println("Sum is " + sum);
        // Now again reuse the method instead of loads of code :)
        sum = test.getSum(2, 4, 5);
        System.out.println("New sum is " + sum);
    }

    public int getSum(int... numbers) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int num : numbers) {
            sum += num;
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

BTW. Your if(truth=true) is assignment to variable called "truth" and will always evaluate to true. Your else will never be called.

Answer (score 0):

Ill take a stab. To reduce boiler plate code you can use methods. Take this example

```
public class MyFooClass {
    private int[] numbers;
    public void doStuff1() {
       // do something
       for(int i=0;i<numbers.length;i++) {
           // check for duplicates or something
       }
    }
    public void doOtherStuff() {
       // do something
       for(int i=0;i<numbers.length;i++) {
           // check for duplicates or something
       }
    }
}
```

as you can see we check for duplicates 2 times, we can reuse that code in another method.

```
public class MyFooClass {
    private int[] numbers;
    public void doStuff1() {
       // do something
       checkForDuplicatesOrSomething();
    }
    public void doOtherStuff() {
       // do something
       checkForDuplicatesOrSomething();
    }
    private void checkForDuplicatesOrSomething() {
       for(int i=0;i<numbers.length;i++) {
           // check for duplicates or something
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Instead of calling `System.out.println("blah blah blah my text");` each time you want to print something you could code your own method like this.

```
    public void p(Object o) { 
           System.out.println(o);
    }
```

Then in your code simply call this method like this:

```
     String s = "foo";
     StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder("i hate this town");
     p(s);
     p(sb1);
```

Comment: Anyone one who down voted care to offer feedback? I think it answers the question in the title.